# How to use flex/grid to center grid in a container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Even though there are a lot of questions on centering divs and what not, for some reason none of them seem to work. Being the css noob that I am with flex/grid, all I know is that I want to have:

- fixed header
- fixed middle content (both horizontally and vertically centered)
- fixed footer

```
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <header className="flex h-20 bg-gray-100 justify-center items-center">
        <span className="font-bold text-2xl">
          title
        </span>
      </header>
    
      <!-- BODY -->
      <div className="flex-1 flex-col mx-auto justify-center items-center max-w-screen-lge p-5">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 items-center">
          <div className="flex col-span-1 h-20 items-center justify-center bg-gray-300">
            1
          </div>
          <div className="flex col-span-1 h-20 justify-end bg-gray-300">
            2
          </div>
          <div className="flex col-span-2 h-12 items-center justify-center bg-gray-300">
           3
          </div>
          <div className="flex col-span-2 h-48 items-center justify-center bg-gray-300">
            4
          </div>
          <div className="flex col-span-2 h-48 items-center justify-center bg-gray-300">
            5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer className="flex h-20 bg-gray-100 justify-center items-center">
        <p>footer text</p>  
      </footer>
    </div>
```

So far it looks like this:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGhN3.png)

How would I center the grid div inside the flex-1 (is that even a right choice?) container?

Edited:
[parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPlug.png)
[content (child)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QrMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you'd do this in tailwind, but here's a minimal example of how you could do it with plain css.

I didn't change your markup in any structural way. Just removed the classnames to make it easier to see what's affecting what.

This squashes up in an undesirable way in the tiny stack overflow snippet window (and you might want to think about that) so you should expand it to see what's going on.

The key to the vertical centering is the flex setup on `.content` which wraps the grid layout:

- make it a flex container via `display: flex`
- ensure it's as tall as the area you want to center in, done here via `min-height: 100vh`
- set `flex-direction: column` so its items stack vertically. (you could do it without this, but this makes more sense to me.)
- set `justify-content: center` to center the content. it centers vertically because that's the flex direction axis.

You could also get there via some combination of [place-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) and either flex or grid.

```css
html, body, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed; /* don't move, no matter what */
  top: 0; /* position fixed removes it from the normal laytou flow, so we should tell it where to be */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  /*
  same as .header above but pinned to bottom instead of top.
  you could reduce repetition by putting the common rules in their
  own class (.fixed or whatever) and then have a secondary class for
  .top or .bottom, but this is fine for the purposes of this demo.
  */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh; /* as tall as the viewport because that's where we want to be centered */
  max-width: 80vw; /* limit width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center horizontally */

  display: flex; /* vertical centering is easy with flex */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; /* see? */
  
  /*
  you could also accomplish the vertical centering with
  flex-direction: row (the default) and align-items: center
  instead of justify-content, but this way makes more sense to
  me for whatever reason
  */
}

.content-grid {
  display: grid; /* establish the grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%); /* for this we only need 2 equal columns */
  grid-template-rows: 70px 50px 100px 100px; /* just ballpark/eyeballed row heights to make it vaguely resemble your example image */
  gap: 1rem; /* space between the blocks */
}

.content-grid > * {
  background: aliceblue; /* just so you can see it */
}

.content-grid > :nth-child(n + 3) { /* 1n + 3 translates as 'every one-th item starting at item 3' */
  /*
  make every block after the first two occupy the entire row.
  start at gridline 1, end at the last one (aka -1)
  */
  grid-column: 1 / -1; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header class="header">
    <span>
      title
    </span>
  </header>

  <!-- BODY -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-grid">
      <div>
        1
      </div>
      <div>
        2
      </div>
      <div>
       3
      </div>
      <div>
        4
      </div>
      <div>
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="footer">
    <p>footer text</p>  
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, so I edited the post to include flex-col (flex-direction: column) and already have justify-center, but it still isnt vertically centered for some reason...

Comment: Is the parent element taller than the content? If you're vertically centering it within a container that's the same height you won't see it.

Comment: yup the parent element is taller. i added 2 more screenshots to the post

Comment: Can you show the rules applied to the parent in the sections styles inspector? Or is this publicly accessible somewhere?

Comment: sorry its on localhost, but here is a screenshot of the styles applied: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC0E3.png

Comment: It’s `display: block`, not `display: flex`. That’s the issue. Add the flex class.